# Python: Mapnik - reading csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, mapnik

How can I use csv-files in mapnik?

I found a csv-module for Mapnik but without good docs.

I want to include csv-file with titles of countries and their population in years into Mapnik and render map with different colours using shapefile.

How can I do it?

And offtopic question: if I open shapefile in xml, how can I get some data in code (some parameters - print titles of countries in console, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation for CSV plugin](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/CSV-Plugin). It won't get any better. If you used other plugins, you'll understand this one.

Now, other parts of your question do not make any sense. I recommend installing [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) and following its documentation, adding shape and csv layers from there and styling as you like. There are some examples for colouring countries.